# Text-based ganglia visualization

Tags: cluster-computing, ganglia

The web based ganglia dashboard is nice. But I'm looking for a simpler dashboard that I can run on text-only terminal. I'm mainly just interested of load of each cluster node. Before writing my own script, does this already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a very simple text based dashboard myself.

https://github.com/hannorein/ganglia_txt_dashboard